# Retrieving data from Shopify Storefront API

Tags: node.js, graphql, fetch, shopify

I am make a simple request to grab data from the **Shopify** Storefront API.

I have confirmed that the store URL and the Storefront access token for my private app are correct. The error I receive is

```
{ errors:
   '[API] Invalid API key or access token (unrecognized login or wrong password)' }.
```

What am I missing here?

```
const query = `
    {
      shop {
        name
        primaryDomain {
          url
          host
        }
      }
    }
;


    fetch('https://<store>.myshopify.com/admin/api/graphql', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(query),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/graphql',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        "X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token": "<storefront-access-token>"
      }
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => console.log(res))
    .catch(response => console.log(response))
```

Comment: Check the devtools console for other error messages and use the Network pane in browser devtools to see what request that response is actually for. If it’s for an OPTIONS request rather than the POST request from your code, then that indicates the CORS preflight OPTIONS request is failing — apparently because that `https://<store>.myshopify.com/admin/api/graphql` API endpoint isn’t CORS-enabled. Specifically, that would indicate the endpoint is expecting authentication credentials in the OPTIONS request. But browsers don’t send the -Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token header in the OPTIONS request

Comment: first you can call this API in postman and check if you getting response than issue in your fetching API method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mistake is really quite simple. Your GraphQL endpoint is wrong. The Storefront API has nothing to do with the /admin API which of course you **cannot call from a publicly authenticated App**.

Try calling the correct endpoint and you will certainly have a better shot at getting the data you need.

```
 https://<store>.myshopify.com/api/graphql
```

All the gory details are here: https://help.shopify.com/en/api/custom-storefronts/storefront-api/getting-started#accessing-the-storefront-api-graphql-endpoint